# SearchBar connected with storyboard is nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar, iboutlet

I'm using Xcode 9.0.

My problem is easy: I dropped a UISearchBar object within a TableViewController. I connected this mySearchBar as an IBOutlet to the TableViewController class:

```
   class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mySearchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.delegate = self

    self.mySearchBar.delegate = self // EXC_BREAKPOINT HERE
    self.myTableView.delegate = self

    self.myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 60.0/255.0, blue: 113.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

The circle to the left is filled - so I'm sure the object is connected properly.
When I run the project it stops at the line above, withe the error message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I tried to:

- clean the project and rebuild
- delete derivedData, clean and rebuild
- delete UIsearchBar object in StoryBoard, drop a new one and reconnect as IBOutlet
- destroy the controller in StoryBoard and recreate a brand new one.

I have no idea to go on. Any help appreciated. I know you can!

EDIT: here a screenshot with the Connections Inspector:[image]

EDIT2: Filtro Localita T is my TableViewController as you can see in this second screenshot [image]

Comment: Add a screenshot of the storyboard with UISearchBar selected and with connections inspector open (left sidebar the last icon there with circle and an arrow)

Comment: And what is Filtro Localita t... since you have your outlet set to `class MyTableViewController:` i would expect to see `MyTableViewController` there

Comment: @Ladislav it is exactly what you expected...

Comment: It is not as expected.  MyTableView and MyTableViewController are not the same thing.  I would expect the class in the right side to be MyTableViewController if you want the outlet hooked up.  Unless you are saying that this is a subclass.

Comment: I know they're not the same :) The class in the right side is FiltroLocalitaTableViewController - that is the name of MyTableViewController. I renamed the code in my first post just to be more understandable... sorry if it created confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was in pushing to this controller. Instead of:

```
let destinationView = FiltroLocalitaTableViewController()
destinationView.palina = self.transito.palina
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationView, animated: true)
```

I used:

```
let filtroLocalitaVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "filtroLocalitaView") as! FiltroLocalitaTableViewController
filtroLocalitaVC.palina = self.transito.palina
filtroLocalitaVC.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(filtroLocalitaVC, animated: true)
```

and it worked.